# Is using a domain for a rest API a good idea?

Tags: rest, azure

This a more general rest api question. Currently we have a rest API that is build with asp web api and is hosted in azure virtual machine. I will have to move the server to another machine, to another account. The service is used by an IOS app that is pre release, so changing the server URL is not a problem. Nonetheless, I would like to now how to handle this in the future. How can I move a web api without breaking the users app. Should I use a domain and change the CNAME records?Or is there a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add something like this to the current server:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://example.com");
```

After that the REST clients can process the 301 response, and store the new location (if they are capable to do that).

Another solution would be to have something like google or a service locator, which can give a link with the actual URI root to the clients. So if they find that the last known URI root is not available, they can ask the service locator about the new one.